# A dragon attacked Winterhold - how do I find Faralda?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I spoke with [Faralda](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Faralda) at the entrance to the [College of Winterhold](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_(place)) and she asked me to perform the [Magelight spell](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Magelight). I bought it from her but before I could cast it a dragon attacked [the city](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Winterhold).

I killed the dragon, but when I return to the college entrance to speak with Faralda *she had gone*.

**How do I find her and [gain entrance](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:First_Lessons) to the College of Winterhold?**

Comment: Did you cast the spell while she was still there? Can you walk in the front gates? Is she still alive? Try looking around to find her body (sounds creepy, I know...)

Comment: I still have the quest to cast the spell, but shes not ther

Answer (score 5):

### tl;dr - Use Console (on PC) or Reload, get rid of the dragon, then talk to Faralda.

---

According to [this list of bugs](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:First_Lessons#Bugs):

> If a dragon attacks before you can cast the spell Faralda has
>   requested, she will disappear entirely from the game

**If you're on PC** you can use the console command:

```
setstage MG01 30
```

This will set the First Lessons quest to the objective where you have cast the required spell and must speak to [Mirabelle Ervine](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mirabelle_Ervine), the Master Wizard.

**If you're not on PC** there seems to be no clear solution. I would recommend reloading a previous save (as soon as possible before the dragon appeared) then hang around [Winterhold](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Winterhold) to see if the dragon attacks this time. If it does then kill it, then attempt to talk to [Faralda](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Faralda). Don't talk to Faralda at all until the dragon is dead or doesn't seem to be arriving at all.

The trigger for the bug seems to be the following events:

1. Talk to Faralda and be asked to perform the spell
2. Dragon attacks Winterhold and is killed
3. Return to [College](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_(place)) entrance to perform spell
4. Faralda has disappeared

Basically you want to avoid having points 1 and 2 run in that order - preferably the reverse.